# Linux alternative to Win+D to show desktop?

Tags: linux, kde, pclinuxos

In Windows, I can type <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to *show desktop* (or to minimize all, the result is the same).

**Is there a similar keystroke in Linux?** Specifically I'm using *PCLinuxOS 2009.2* .

Comment: There will be a way to remap the keys to get precisely your desired result. Have a look in the PCLinuxOS documentation for laptops or intel Macs and there should be info on keyboard customization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> does the same thing.